# silently call a dynamic JSP page with jQuery and pass URL variables to that page

Tags: jquery, jsp, url, xhtml, dynamic

I want to call a dynamic JSP page and pass data to it so it will run a query on my database and then return a set of results.

I would like to do this without a visible page refresh.

So in essence i want to pass two parameters to the dynamic page, policyID and columnID.  These will vary depending on which tab (policyId) is active and which table column has been clicked on (columnID).  These need to be passed without visible page refresh to the external JSP which takes these and uses them to query the database.  This then returns a set of results i want to display on screen via jQuery.

Would i use the .get method for this?  Is it possible to interact with the server side in this way without page refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is what you want

Read up on jQuery.ajax in the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). All well explained

Comment: I just didn't want to return XML though.

Just wanted to run a query, buidl the table etc and then return this to the current page only.

Comment: AJAX does not have to be XML. Read the docs it handles, XML, JSON, HTML, etc. There are hundred of samples on the web using jQuery AJAX